# SSL handshake fails when disabling TLS1.0

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I've disabled TLS1.0 in my webservers and am able to connect directly to the nodes using TLS1.1 and TLS1.2. However when I try to connect via a F5 loadbalancer using TLS1.1, TLS1.2 or TLS1.0 the connection fails on SSL handshake. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect LoadBalancerip:443 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
no peer certificate available
No client certificate CA names sent
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
```

---

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: You should probably enlist SNI with `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1_2 -servername <hostname>`. Possible related: [openssl clienthello ironport f5](http://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+clienthello+ironport+f5). Is it one of the buggy F5's, or is it an updated one?

Comment: Noticed I never updated this old issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with F5, which needed an upgrade. The older F5 was doing node health check using TLS1.0 . But since I'd disabled TLS1.0 in the individual nodes, the F5 could not do so. Upgrading F5 resolved this issue.